# How can I define a unknown value in a function?

Tags: matlab

I have a m.file as,

```
for ii=1:40
    m=round(X(ii,:)); % X is a matrix (40*1)
.
.
end
```

also, I have a function as,

```
function cost=MY_Fun(X)

 IW_Num=m*7;LW_Num=1*m;b1_Num=m*1;b2_Num=1*1;
.
.
end
```

Because value of m in function is not known, I get an error. How can I define value of m in function so that each value of m from "for..end" loop be defined in function??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try declaring the variable m global

http://www.mathworks.in/help/matlab/ref/global.html

OR

You can pass the value of m to the function as a parameter

Comment: Good practice is to avoid globals if possible

Comment: How can I use global in my function? Can you explain more?Thanks

Comment: To make global you have to just add global var_name. Eg Add global m after the function cost=MY_Fun(X) line.

Comment: I wrote: function cost=MY_Fun(X)
global m .. end ; I get: m=[] ! What is my mistake??

Comment: Thank you so much. I think that my problem has been solved :)

Comment: @AdityaPande Excuse me, I wanna make global a variable in function, and use that variable in main m.file.How can I do it??! I wrote             function cost=MY_Fun(X)
global m .. end, and wrote "global m" in main m.file;but, I get m=[]. please help me

Answer (score 1):

You can put `m` as an argument in your function:

```
function cost=MY_Fun(X,m)

 IW_Num=m*7;LW_Num=1*m;b1_Num=m*1;b2_Num=1*1;
.
.
end
```

Note that Matlab is good at applying its functions to arrays, so your first loop might be unnecessary, you could use:

```
m=round(X);
```

And then call your function with `m(ii)`;

Comment: I need my first loop, because it is in an another my cost function. I wrote:                                                     function cost=MY_Fun(X,m)

 IW_Num=m*7;LW_Num=1*m;b1_Num=m*1;b2_Num=1*1;
.
.
end                                                                        but I have an error : Input argument "m" is undefined. how can I define m in this function???

Comment: @skbn please explain more precisely in your question what you are ultimately trying to achieve.

Comment: I have a function that a " for..end" loop is used in that. In this loop for each value of m, My_Fun function is called. this function need to value of m. I don'i know how call or define the value of m in this function.

Comment: @skbn have you tried what I wrote in my answer? Calling the function MY_Fun with an extra argument `m`? Example: `MY_Fun(X, m)` You need to edit the function to take an extra argument called `m`.